# Css element Max-Size

Tags: css, overflow, maxlength

What is major differences in using these css rules

div{width:100px; overflow:hidden;}

**And**

div{max-width:100px; overflow:hidden!important;}

Is there going to be any cross-compatibility Issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max-width` is great for stating *"don't go any bigger than this, but it's OK if it's smaller"*.

This might be great if you were doing say a speech bubble that could be dynamic in size (depending on content) and you wanted the div surrounding speech bubble to vary.

`width` on the other hand says *"the must be 100px"*, which means even if the content within the div is smaller, the surrounding div will still be 100px.

Example:
http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/photo1.png

Comment: But there is tendency  "if you say this must be 100px" and the contents inside the element is larger this may cause overflow.

Comment: i want to know more about the cross-compatibility Issues thanks

Comment: Unless your users are using IE6, you should be OK as both properties are CSS2 - I haven't run into any issues before. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

Answer (score 0):

`max-width: 100px` is not different from `width: 100px` if you do not have `width` specified. And the `!important` flag only prevents from overriding the property, so it depends on the context if that makes a difference.

Comment: max-width: 100px  is variable width up to 100px, this could be 20px or sometime 80px but it stop increment at 100px, while   width: 100px is fixed width. So there is difference.

Comment: Yep, that is true. I did not say it was unconditionally different. Nevertheless thanks for the clarification.